# javascript click nearest asp button

Tags: javascript, telerik, closest

I have javascript that will fire an alert box when the enter key is pressed within a telerik RadAutoCompleteBox. When enter is pressed i need to find the nearest asp.net (input button) and click this. Any Suggestions?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var handler = Telerik.Web.UI.RadAutoCompleteBox.prototype._onKeyDown;
        Telerik.Web.UI.RadAutoCompleteBox.prototype._onKeyDown = function (e) {
            handler.apply(this, [e]); // Let AutoCompleteBox finish it's internal logic
            if (e.keyCode == Sys.UI.Key.enter) {
                this._onBlur();

                alert('Enter has been pressed inside RadAutoCompleteBox');
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for since it requires jQuery, at any rate here are 2 options. One going through a parent element and then looking through the child elements, the second if they are on the same level through siblings.

```js
$('#textbox').on('keyup', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('input[type="button"]').click();
});

$('#thebutton').on('click', function() {
  alert('the click happened');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <input type="text" id="textbox">
  <input type="button" id="thebutton" value="click me">
</div>
```

```js
$('#textbox').on('keyup', function() {
  $(this).siblings('input[type="button"]').click();
});

$('#thebutton').on('click', function() {
  alert('the click happened');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox">
<input type="button" id="thebutton" value="click me">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closest() to find the nearest "button type" input or button tag

```
if (e.keyCode == Sys.UI.Key.enter) {
    // Code
    var input = $(e.target).closest('input[type="button"],input[type="submit"],button');
    if (input.lenght > 0) {
        input.click();
    }
}
```

This will search the element itself and later will traverse up through its ancestors in the DOM tree to find the first match and click it